# XML Load repeated elements using c#

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Is that possible to loop element with the same orientation of fields.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xml>
    <document>
        <sls>                                           
            <ppsitecode>0062</ppsitecode>                                           
            <ppsitedesc><![CDATA[AAAAAAA]]></ppsitedesc>                                            
            <ppqty>1.00</ppqty>                                         
            <ppunit>C24</ppunit>                                            
            <ppsitecode>0269</ppsitecode>                                           
            <ppsitedesc><![CDATA[BBBBBBB]]></ppsitedesc>                                            
            <ppqty>1.00</ppqty>                                         
            <ppunit>C24</ppunit>                                            
            <ppsitecode>2546</ppsitecode>                                           
            <ppsitedesc><![CDATA[CCCCCCC]]></ppsitedesc>                                            
            <ppqty>1.00</ppqty>                                         
            <ppunit>C24</ppunit>
        </sls>
    </document>
</xml>
```

Using the xml file above. Please refer to the desire output below:

```
ppsitecode   ppsitedesc   ppqty     ppunit
0062         AAAAAAA      1.00      C24
0269         BBBBBBB      1.00      C24
2546         CCCCCCC      1.00      C24
```

Answer (score 0):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication83
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement sls = doc.Descendants("sls").FirstOrDefault();

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            string[] columns = sls.Elements().Select(x => x.Name.LocalName).Distinct().ToArray();

            foreach (string column in columns)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(column, typeof(string));
            }

            DataRow newRow = null;
            foreach (XElement element in sls.Elements())
            {
                string columnName = element.Name.LocalName;
                if (columnName == "ppsitecode") newRow = dt.Rows.Add();

                newRow[columnName] = (string)element;
            }


        }



    }



}
```